# 3 separate fields,one views exposed filter

Tags: views

I would like to have a Rent/Sell radio button for 3 content types.
Then I want to show this radio buttons on a views exposed filter.
How is this possible to do without sharing the radio buttons field on the 3 content types i.e. use a different field on each content type (so as to make easier to upgrade to D8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add all 3 fields as exposed filters and hide 2 of them (with CSS or if you set all fields as "hidden" type with [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)). Then you can use the visible field as master and alter values of the two others with a `#submit` callback.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if (isset($form['field_to_expose1'])) {
        // Hide two fields and left one exposed.
        $form['field_to_hide2']['#type'] = 'hidden';
        $form['field_to_hide3']['#type'] = 'hidden';

        // Execute set_value_for_hidden_fields() as first function submit on $form['#submit'] array.
        array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'set_value_for_hidden_fields');
    }
}

function set_value_for_hidden_fields($form, &$form_state) {
  $value = $form_state['values']['field_to_expose1'];

  // Modify form_state values of concerned field.
  $form_state['values']['field_to_hide2'] = $value;
  $form_state['values']['field_to_hide3'] = $value;

  // Modify form_state of concerned field to pass to the view.
  $form_state['view']->display_handler->handlers['filter']['field_to_hide2']->validated_exposed_input = $value;
  $form_state['view']->display_handler->handlers['filter']['field_to_hide3']->validated_exposed_input = $value;
}
```

That's unstested code, but I hope you get the idea.

But is it worth the effort? Is sharing a field between multiple content types really a blocking issue when planning an upgrade? I'm not well informed on upgrade procedures for D7 to 8, but sharing a field between content types seems to be a pretty common thing using D7.

Comment: Thank you!As far as I have read,D8 won't support sharing a field between content types.So this would make the upgrade difficult.Has anybody more info on this?

Comment: Or am I wrong?I just found this:"A field cannot be "shared" across entity types,
only across bundles of a given entity type"
Does this mean that fields can be shared also on D8 between content types?

Comment: So you won't be able to share a field between a node, user or term, not blocking for you :).