# 1 Views Filter (exposed) for 2 fields

Tags: views

I am interested in having one view filter for two separate fields.

Example:
In a staff directory I am working on, users have both a "First Name" and "Nickname" field.

The output results show both, but in order to keep it user-friendly, I would like to have a "First Name" filter that sorts by both "First Name" and "Nickname" based on the input.

[image]

I found this question on here and it seems like it gives the proper direction of what I am looking for but I am not quite sure how to execute this solution.

[3 separate fields,one views exposed filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/143821/3-separate-fields-one-views-exposed-filter)

The suggestion based on the question above would be to expose both the "First Name" and "Nickname" filters but to hide the "Nickname" filter with CSS.

Following that, if a user typed a name such as "John" into the "First Name" filter and then clicked "Submit", before the query is executed, the input value "John" would also be automatically input into the CSS-hidden "Nickname" filter.

The concept makes sense to me but I am confused as to how to execute it.

Are there any detailed guides that could explain how I could make that happen?
With the PHP code given in the question linked above, would I have to modify a core file? Would it be in a template file? Would it have to be in a module file?

Or is there an even simpler solution to this that I am not thinking about?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Hey Andrew no news good news ? Did you try my answer? 100% tested and guaranted ;)

Comment: Hi Kojo! I apologize for not replying sooner. It definitely does work and is great! But I will need to use it in the future. In this particular example, it did not quite work 100% for me. If I searched for "Veronica Lopez", it would bring back all people with first names "Veronica" and all people with last names "Lopez" rather than just any people named "Veronica Lopez". Since it's a directory and needs to be that specific, I will split the filters but for something more general in the future I will be using this!!

Comment: Yep no worries I'm glad to know it helped. "Veronica Lopez" as a unique string search is indeed another feature request IMO, especially if you want a Combine fields filter at the same time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with an exposed **Global Combine fields filter** ? I'm not sure which Views version implemented that filter.

[image: exposed Global Combine fields filter]

Alternatively, you may use the [Views filters populate](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) module :

1. Add the fields you want to search in a OR combination of filters, not exposed.
2. Add the **Global : Populate filters** provided by the module (exposed),  checking the filters you added in the Or group.